# CS50 Finance "Buy" Function not returning correct error

Tags: flask, cs50

I am trying to implement the buy function of the flask code and as a test, I am trying to get the two error codes that I have so far in the buy function to work. However, no matter what I input into the form, I always get returned to the error page stating "Must Provide Username" and I am not sure how it is getting to that point instead of one of my two error conditions.

Here is my buy function so far:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    # requested_quote = stock
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not request.form.get("symbol"):
            return apology("must provide symbol", 403)
        if not request.form.get("amount") or request.form.get("amount") < 1:
            return apology("Please enter amount 1 or greater", 403)

        stock = request.form.get("symbol")
        amount = request.form.get("amount")
        requested_quote = lookup(request.form.get("quote"))
        cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :id", session["user_id"])

        if requested_quote == None:
            return apology ("Invalid Symbol", 400)
        if (requested_quote["price"] * amount) > cash:
            return apology("Not enough funds", 400)
        else:
             db.execute("INSERT INTO purchases (id, symbol, amount, share_price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",
             (session["user_id"], stock, amount, requested_quote["price"]))
    else:
        return render_template("buy.html")
```

Here is the login function, which was included with the assignment's distribution code, and I think might be related to my issue

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
                          username=request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

and also this:

```
def login_required(f):
    """
    Decorate routes to require login.

    http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/viewdecorators/
    """
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get("user_id") is None:
            return redirect("/login")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: "Must Provide Username" -- where exactly it is returned?  The name of the error sounds like `@login_required` is calling it. If so `@login_required` is executed before any of the code above -- no need to debug what is written above.

Comment: what is the `action` attribute of the `form` element in `buy.html`?

Comment: @kate-melnykova Okay, so when I get THAT error, it returns before the rest of my code?  Thank you, that does give me a place to start.  Unfortunately I am confused about it, because there is another "Login" function that is given in this assignment's distribution code, so I am unsure why there would be something wrong with it.  I will post the other parts of my code into my original post.  Thanks.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I can't believe I missed it, but the form action was to go back to the login page.  I can't believe I missed that detail, I had just assumed it was an error in my flask code.  Thank you so much for the help, this is the answer!  Is there a way I can mark your comment as the answer?  Sorry, but I am still new to this.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the flask log in the terminal where `flask run` is executed. It is likely to show that the buy route is not being called at all. Check the action attribute of the form element in buy.html. Perhaps login.html was copied to buy.html as a starting point, and that attribute was never changed.